# Electron.js rebinding this to global - bind(), call() not working as intended

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So I'm moving my code base to an electron wrapper and I have been chipping away at the problems.

One of which is that I designed a factory that creates "Plugins", I feed it with functions, data and other things (like mounted functions etc). Similar to how Vue creates it's components.

videobridgeTransmitter.js :

```
const videoBridgeTransmitter = {
    id: 'videobridge',
    data: {
        availableSources : [], //available Sources that can be streamed
        selectedSources: [], //selected sources by the user
        shared: {
            activeClients: []
        }
    },
    mounted: function(){
        console.log(this.client) //prints global

        this.client.setPluginData('videobridge', {
            streams : [],
            addStream(stream, alias, deviceID){
              this.streams.push({
                  alias: alias,
                  deviceID : deviceID,
                  dataStream : stream
              })
            }, ...
```

In the factory class I rebind all methods to the new instance:

```
//rebind "this" to the plugin object, so that we can access the plugin from the methods
    const methodKeys = Object.keys(methods);
    for (let i=0;i < methodKeys.length;i++){
      methods[methodKeys[i]] = methods[methodKeys[i]].bind(this);
    }
```

The methods are later called via plugin.methods.xyz(args);

When I first run the instance, I call its mounted function:

```
  if (typeof plugin.mounted === 'function'){
    plugin.mounted.call(this);
  }
```

This all worked fine. However in electron I face the issue, that it tells me "this" is now "global". I checked in the debugger, when it binds this, it binds the correct scope.

However somehow when it then gets executed, this is rebound to "global"

Comment: You're binding `this` to `plugin.mounted` already, so no need to `plugin.mounted.call(this)`. The whole approach here look error-prone. If you're writing a plugin system, will plug authors be aware of the subtleties of your rebound `this`? In my experience, `this` is toxic and leads to plenty of bugs when you use it in this way. Pass stuff explicitly. Don't tie the workings of your functions to some implicit hidden state.

Comment: i.e. why not change the function signature to `function mounted(client){}` and have your "runner" pass in the client?

Comment: methods and mounted are two different objects. Methods are called from the front end.

I agree passing in is more verbose, but it seemed redundant.